# Event Delivery limit always exceeded

Tags: platform-event

We have encountered an issue where a flow that creates platform events was triggered over 200k times. Our event relay is now constantly working to send these events.

- We have tried deleting the channel and event relay but the events remain.
- Is there any way to delete these events so our allocation is not always full?
- Will deleting the platform event definition fix this?

[image]